# Import suggestions are not showing up in JetBrains PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, code-completion

For some reason not able to get import suggestions in PyCharm. It was working fine but suddenly all stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out several options.

I reverted back the import settings all started working again

[image]

[image]